# integrante keycloak with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, keycloak

I need some help, I need to integrate a simple web environment with authentication via keycloak, I already have all the data, I performed tests using postman and I manage to generate the access token normally, but when I perform the authentication on the login screen, after it gives me an error in the url ending with /token, which is used to generate the user's access token and session, could someone help me, I'll leave it as listed as I left it configured in my project the keycloak

result in postman:
[image]

```
keycloak.json

{
  "realm": "interno",
  "auth-server-url": "private-url/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "acd-pr",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "private code"
  },
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

```
app.module.ts

function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: "../assets/keycloak.json",
        realm: "interno",
        clientId: "acd-pr",
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: "login-required",
        checkLoginIframe: false,
      },
    });
}

providers: [
    KeycloakService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
    },
  ]
```

```
auth.guard.ts

import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  Router,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
} from "@angular/router";
import { KeycloakAuthGuard, KeycloakService } from "keycloak-angular";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class AuthGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {
  constructor(
    protected readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    super(router, keycloak);
  }

  public async isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    // Force the user to log in if currently unauthenticated.
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      await this.keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url,
      });
    } else {
      alert(this.authenticated);
    }

    return true;
  }
```

```
erro console chrome

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 () 
https://private-url/auth/realms/interno/protocol/openid-connect/token
```